# Best way to approach a Model belonging to one of many possible models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have a bunch of Models, Articles, Downloads, Videos, Pictures, I want to be able to have comments on all these models with a single Comment model so I can track comments made by a certain user across all these models. What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: After looking around a bit, I found [this screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association) to be very helpful as well, if anyone else is also looking.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what **polymorphic associations** were designed for.

Check http://guides.rails.info/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Basically you would do something like this:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :user
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end
# ... so on
```

Check the link above for how to design your migration. You want `commentable_id` and `commentable_type` columns, instead of the imageable_* ones they use in the example.